# React typescript cant trigger a state change within a catch

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this state

```
const [error, setError] = useState<any>(false);
```

That is supposed to get trigged when a catch happens

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`${backendUrl}/${filteredlocation}`)
      .then(res => {
        setData((state:any) => [...state, res?.data]);
      }).catch({
        
        setError(false);

      });
  }, []);
```

But for some reason i keep getting

> Argument of type '{ setError(: any): any; }' is not assignable to
> parameter of type '(reason: any) => PromiseLike'.   Object
> literal may only specify known properties, and 'setError' does not
> exist in type '(reason: any) => PromiseLike'.

And i cannot set a new state, what is going on?

Answer (score 4):

`.catch` needs you to pass it a function, but you're missing that in your code. This:

```
.catch({
  setError(false);
})
```

...should be this:

```
.catch(() => {
  setError(false);
})
```